# VBA Application Defined Error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to iterate through a row of numbers (Col A).  Many of the numbers are duplicates, and I'm going to put how many times each number appears in Column F in a row corresponding to the original number.  However, I keep getting a Application Defined Error before my End If code.

```
Sub Iterate()

    Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Select
    Dim iVal As Long
    Dim duplicate As Long
    duplicate = Cells(2, 1).Value
    For i = 3 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If ActiveCell(i, 1).Value <> duplicate Then
            iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A"), ActiveCell(i, 1).Value)
            duplicate = iVal
        End If
            iVal = duplicate
            Cells(i, 6).Value = iVal
    Next
End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a typo to me.  `Range("A1:A")` should probably be `Range("A:A")`

Answer (score 0):

Use a collection object when you want a list of unique items. In this case, you want to count how many times something is duplicated, so in our error catching routine we get the current number of duplicates, add 1 to it, then drop the item from the collection and re-add it with the new count.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim myCol As New Collection
Dim IncrementedValue As Integer

'Because you start on row 3, we have to add 2 to the row count
For i = 3 To Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 2
    On Error GoTo DupFound
    myCol.Add 1, Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Text
    On Error GoTo 0
Next

'Because you start on row 3, we have to add 2 to the row count
For i = 3 To Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 2
    Sheet1.Cells(i, 6).Value = myCol.Item(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Text)
Next
Exit Sub

DupFound:
IncrementedValue = myCol.Item(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Text) + 1
myCol.Remove Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Text
myCol.Add IncrementedValue, Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Text
Resume Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  However, I tried inserting this code and I'm getting an Run-time error message '5' - Invalid procedure call or argument.  Any ideas what this could be?  I believe it's something to do with the excel data rather than the code because I couldn't find any errors, although I'm unsure as I'm relatively new to VBA.  Thanks.

Comment: @bmyers Entirely my bad. The key property of a collection is a string so we have to pass the `.Text` property of the cell instead of the `.Value` property. I corrected the code (and tested it this time).

Comment: Thank you!  Greatly appreciated