# failes to send mail after first in loop

Tags: vba, excel

Got a macro running through columns with mail addresses using most parts from **Ron de Bruin**. 
The macro runs through just fine, but only sends the first hit in `column B` and doesn't display any of the other hits when i try to watch it? What could be the issue?

The code is so that I can get the default signature from outlook, thats why it's `.Display` first in the code.

```
Sub mail_HTML()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Working in Office 2000-2016
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim strbody As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error GoTo cleanup
For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
       LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value) = "yes" Then

strbody = "<H3>Hei " & Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value & "</H3>" _
             & "<p>" & Range("k4") & "<p>"

         On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .Display
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = Range("K12").Value
            .HTMLBody = strbody & .HTMLBody
            'You can add files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add Range("O1").Value
            .Send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

cleanup:
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It fails because you set `OutMail` to `Nothing` within the loop but never insantiate it again within the loop. The code won't fail because of your `On Error Resume Next` line. Try setting `OutMail` within the loop.

Comment: @Ambie that was it! Thx

Comment: Could you also give me a hint on why the attachment wont load (and yes I'm aware that I have removed it;))

Comment: You should pose a new question for that.

Comment: Figured it out. Just me being lazy

Comment: The root of the problem is misuse of on Error Resume Next. Restrict use to where it is appropriate so you see errors to fix. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31753321/1571407

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set

```
Set OutMail = Nothing
```

You dont have any access to the object anymore (because it is destroyed). But you set it before the loop. You need to set it in every loop then like this:

```
    On Error Resume Next
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
        .Display
        .To = cell.Value
        .Subject = Range("K12").Value
        .HTMLBody = strbody & .HTMLBody
        'You can add files also like this
        '.Attachments.Add Range("O1").Value
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
```

So after 1 Email the oject is destroyed, but you are not aware because of the on error resume next

Answer (score 0):

```
Tried that but it is not working for me, here is my code:
Do Until in_file.EOF
Email_To = in_file!email_address
Email_Bcc = ""
Email_Body = in_file!email_salut & " " & in_file!email_name & ", test this."
Email_Subject = "Email Subject"
Set mail_object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set mail_single = mail_object.CreateItem(0)

With mail_single
    .Subject = Email_Subject
    .To = Email_To
    .cc = Email_Cc
    .BCC = Email_Bcc
    .Body = Email_Body
    .send
End With

Set mail_object = Nothing
Set mail_single = Nothing

in_file.MoveNext
```

Loop

Comment: This adds an EOF idea that is not applicable to the question. If you use this consider moving `Set mail_object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` before `Do Until in_file.EOF` and moving `Set mail_object = Nothing` after `Loop`.