# Windows 10 / Office 2016 - Selected item is not attaching when I run my macro

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010, outlook-2016

For some reason, I can't get the selected item which would be an email from my inbox to attach as an attachment when I create a new mail from my macro.  I'm using Windows 10 / Outlook 2016.  I had this working in Windows 7 Office 2010, but I'm not sure why it's not working now.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub SendEmail()
    Dim Inbox As Object
    Dim MyItem As Object
    Dim AddEmail As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    Dim iAnswer As VbMsgBoxResult


    'Check if User wants to copy an existing email to new form
    iAnswer = MsgBox(Prompt:=" Do you want to copy the selected email to new form? (If you select YES, Keep the current email selected - DO NOT SELECT ANOTHER EMAIL - Until you finish sending)", _
    Buttons:=vbYesNo, Title:="Copy Selected Email")
    If iAnswer = vbYes Then
        AddEmail = True
    End If

    'Check Version of Outlook (2007 vs 2010)
    If Outlook.Application.Version = "12.0.0.6680" Then
        On Error GoTo FolderError:
        Set Inbox = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("Mailbox - @Incoming_Workshare")
        On Error Resume Next
    Else
        On Error GoTo FolderError:
        Set Inbox = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("@Incoming_Workshare")
        On Error Resume Next
    End If


    'Open Form From Folder (The Inbox =)
    Set MyItem = Inbox.Items.Add("IPM.Note.Workflow Sharing 2016")
    MyItem.Display
    MyItem.Subject = "Automatically Generated Based on Job Information"

    'Check Version of VBA and Form to make sure you are using latest macro
    If Not MyItem.Mileage = 11 Then
        'Check if User wants to copy an existing email to new form
        iAnswer = MsgBox(Prompt:="ALERT - Macro has been updated - Select Yes to Update" & vbCrLf & "(Note: Outlook will be restarted)", _
          Buttons:=vbYesNo, Title:="Automatic Macro Update")
        If iAnswer = vbYes Then
            Shell "wscript C:\Macro\UpdateOutlookMacro.vbs", vbNormalFocus
        End If
    End If

    'Copy Selected Emails to New Email if you selected Yes
    If AddEmail = True Then 
        'Check if a there is a reference to the long access time projects in the subject or body to add instructions to also send as attachment (LARGE PROJECTS)
        If InStr(1, UCase(ActiveExplorer().Selection.Item(1).Subject), "TUCAN") > 0 Or _
           InStr(1, UCase(ActiveExplorer().Selection.Item(1).Subject), "RUDY") > 0 Or _
           InStr(1, UCase(ActiveExplorer().Selection.Item(1).Subject), "SARGENT") > 0 Then
            MyItem.HTMLBody = "<b>Additional Instructions from Originating Location:</b>" & Chr(11) & "PLEASE SEND BACK HYPERLINKS AND ATTACHMENTS FOR ALL EDITED FILES" & Chr(11) & Chr(11) & Chr(11) & Chr(11) & "---------------------------------------------" & Chr(11) & "Original Banker Email:" & Chr(11)
        Else
            MyItem.HTMLBody = "<b>Additional Instructions from Originating Location:</b>" & Chr(11) & Chr(11) & Chr(11) & Chr(11) & Chr(11) & "---------------------------------------------" & Chr(11) & "Original Banker Email:" & Chr(11)
        End If

        MyItem.BodyFormat = olFormatRichText

        'Check large job 15MB
        If (ActiveExplorer().Selection.Item(1).Size >= 15728640) Then
            MsgBox "Alert! The attached original email size is " & Format(ActiveExplorer().Selection.Item(1).Size / 1048576, 0#) & " MBs. There are errors when sending large emails. Please save attachments as links to reduce the filesize.", , Title:="Email Size Too Big"
        End If

        MyItem.Attachments.Add ActiveExplorer().Selection.Item(1)

        'Check if Sender is an autoforward from a mailbox, alerting to be manually updated
        MyItem.UserProperties("Clocker") = ActiveExplorer().Selection.Item(1).SenderName + "; " + ActiveExplorer().Selection.Item(1).CC

        If MyItem.UserProperties("Clocker") = "OH Mail; " Or MyItem.UserProperties("Clocker") = "NO Mail; " Or MyItem.UserProperties("Clocker") = "LAV Mail; " Or MyItem.UserProperties("Clocker") = "OK Mail; " Or MyItem.UserProperties("Clocker") = "WY Mail; " Then
            'MsgBox "Alert! Please populate the Requestor/Clocker field. It cannot be listed as the Advisory Presentation Mailbox"
            'MyItem.UserProperties("Clocker") = "" ' Removed Q4
            Dim CorrectedClocker1, CorrectedClocker2, CorrectedClocker3 As String
            Correctedclocker1 = Trim(SuperMid(ActiveExplorer().Selection.Item(1).body, "From:", "Sent:"))
            If InStr(ActiveExplorer().Selection.Item(1).body, "Cc:") > 0 Then
                CorrectedClocker2 = Trim(SuperMid(ActiveExplorer().Selection.Item(1).body, "To:", "Cc:"))
                CorrectedClocker3 = Trim(SuperMid(ActiveExplorer().Selection.Item(1).body, "Cc:", "Subject:"))
            Else
                CorrectedClocker2 = Trim(SuperMid(ActiveExplorer().Selection.Item(1).body, "To:", "Subject:"))
                CorrectedClocker3 = ""
            End If

            CorrectedClocker2 = Replace(CorrectedClocker2, "@Completed", "")
            CorrectedClocker3 = Replace(CorrectedClocker3, "@Completed", "")

            MyItem.UserProperties("Clocker") = CorrectedClocker1 & "; " & CorrectedClocker2 & "; " & CorrectedClocker3

        Else
            If InStr(MyItem.UserProperties("Clocker"), "[Cvcs]") > 0 Then
```

Comment: What exactly does "I can't get the selected item which would be an email from my inbox to attach as an attachment" mean? Do you get an error? Or an unexpected result?

Comment: I receive an unexpected result.  I run my macro which opens my new email and it's suppose to automatically attached the selected mail from my mailbox, but it's not attaching. For example: "I select an email I want to attach in a new email.  So, I click on my macro and a new mail opens with the required fields but without the attached email.  Which should attach.

Comment: The `If Outlook.Application.Version = "12.0.0.6680" Then` is too specific. The Inbox reference goes to the 2007 version `Set Inbox = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("@Incoming_Workshare")`. There should be an error here. If this is the problem you could drop the test and use `Set Inbox = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("Mailbox - @Incoming_Workshare")`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31753201/vba-how-long-does-on-error-resume-next-work/31753321#31753321

Comment: I'm not having an error with the mailbox.  I'm having an error with opening new emails without the selected email attaching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this running inside Outlook VBA?. Should Attachments.Add line be the following?

```
MyItem.Attachments.Add Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
```

Get rid of the "On Error Resume Next" statements - they are hiding runtime errors.

Comment: I was able to use your line.  It worked when I placed it before " 'Check large job 15MB ".  It works!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a mailbox item as an attachment to a new message.
You need to set the [Outlook.OlAttachmentType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/attachments/attach-an-outlook-contact-item-to-an-email-message) property to olEmbeddeditem.
You can add a mail item as an attachment by referring to the code below.

```
Sub ResolveName()

 Dim myItem As Object

 Dim Item As Object

 Dim myFolder As Folder
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set myFolder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
 Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
 Set Item = myFolder.Items(2)
'Item.Display
 myItem.Attachments.Add Item, Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, 1, "first"
 myItem.Display
End Sub
```