# Debugging Outlook.MailItem

Tags: vba, outlook

I have downloaded an Outlook.MailItem to my `Y:\` folder at the location:

```
Y:\email.msg
```

In Outlook VBA, I want to test a script on this item. However, I am not sure how to define it.

I have the following:

```
Dim testMail As MailItem
Set testMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
```

But how do I make the link to the exact item I stored?

---

After that I want to test storing the attachment in this file using the code (which sometimes, not always produces a corrupted file):

```
Public Sub Save_File(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    On Error Resume Next

    ' init
    Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim folderSave As String
    Dim yyyymmdd As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim fileNameFull As String

    ' date @T (midnight 00:00)
    Dim mydate As Date
    mydate = MItem.ReceivedTime

    ' filename and path
    yyyymmdd = get_yyyymmdd_prevday(mydate)


    folderSave = "V:\Operations\"
    fileName = yyyymmdd & "-FileToStore.csv"


    fileNameFull = folderSave & fileName

    For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments

        If fileExist(fileNameFull) = False Then
            ' if file does not exist
            oAttachment.SaveAsFile fileNameFull
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

And the help function:

```
Public Function get_yyyymmdd_prevday(mydate As Date) As String
    Dim yyyymmddstr As String
    'Previous Business Date

    Dim yyyy As String
    Dim mm As String
    Dim dd As String


    If Weekday(mydate) = 2 Then
        mydate = mydate - 3
    Else
        mydate = mydate - 1
    End If


    yyyy = Year(mydate)
    mm = Month(mydate)
    dd = Day(mydate)

    If Month(mydate) < 10 Then
        mm = "0" & mm
    End If
    If Day(mydate) < 10 Then
        dd = "0" & dd
    End If

    ' -->
    yyyymmddstr = yyyy & "_" & mm & "_" & dd
    get_yyyymmdd_prevday = yyyymmddstr
End Function
```

Comment: As far as I know there's no easy way to create an object from a downloaded mail item in this way.  The [`MailItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem) object is intended for mail that exists within the application.  Perhaps if you explain further what you're trying to test, there are alternate solutions.

Comment: I am trying to test a vba script that downloads the attachment of an Outlook Item. Usually it works fine, but this time it stored a corrupted file. So I want to debug the code to see why this happens.

Comment: perhaps if you share your vba...

Comment: Added the code to debug the part that corrupts the file when storing it. However, it does not always corrupt store it, just once in a while. Thus why I wanted to understand when it happens, thus I need to know how to debug it

Comment: ...only certain mail messages presumably?  (as in, reproducible?)

Comment: Taking certain mail messages is already defined, there is no problem with that. Basically I filter on the receiver and subject line and if it has an attachment.

Comment: is the attachment always `csv`? is the file okay before saving it?

Answer (score 1):

To reference a .msg file there is `OpenSharedItem`.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Reference_msg_file()

    Dim testMailPathFile As String
    Dim testMail As MailItem

    testMailPathFile = "Y:\email.msg"

    Set testMail = Session.OpenSharedItem(testMailPathFile)
    'testMail.Display

    Save_File testMail

ExitRoutine:
    Set testMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

You have disabled debugging with `On Error Resume Next`. Remove this line and investigate how to make use of it before applying it to any future code.

Comment: How to apply On Error Resume Next https://stackoverflow.com/a/31753321/1571407 . Let the editor pop open rather than hide unforeseen errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could change “On Error Resume Next ” to “On Error GoTo Handler”.

You could use this to debug Outlook.MailItem

For more information, you could reference this link:

[On Error Statement (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/on-error-statement)