# How to Print an Array in the body of an outlook mail?

Tags: arrays, vba, email, outlook

I am carrying out a project for my company. I have created an array and stored some data inside.

I need to print or paste the array in the body of an email.

You can notice below that in the object .Body = "Hello, " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Could you confirm the net amount below?" & T(p + 1, 8)

The array T(p+1,8) doesn't appear in the body of the mail.

Below the code:

---

On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail

.to = Address

.CC = "otcequityderivativesettlement@xxxxxx.com"

.BCC = ""

.Subject = "Amount to confirm Value Date" & " " & VALUEDATE & " " & CTPY

.Body = "Hello, " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Could you confirm the net amount below?" & T(p + 1, 8)

.Attachments.Add "R:\Fmp\Fmp10\All\POLE DERIVES ACTIONS\SSI xxxxx\SSI xxxx.pdf"

.Display

```
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
```

Comment: The main error is misuse of `On Error Resume Next`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31753201/vba-how-long-does-on-error-resume-next-work Remove it and fix any errors previously bypassed. Put in enough code so potential respondents may copy and run immediately. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Provide a sample of the array.

Comment: The code is very long and repetitive. Each time I paste codes on the forum people are disappointed. Anyway I will do/ Blow, the code:

Comment: Try to cut the code down to something that can be copied and run, as described in the link provided https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve "Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem". Especially remove On Error Resume Next unless it is used appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Sub Macro()


Dim i As Variant

Dim l As Long

Dim p As Long

Dim mySIay() As Variant

Dim DataRange As Range

Dim cell As Range

Dim x As Long

Dim CSico As Long

Dim CTradeID As Long

Dim CBusinessEvent As Long

Dim CNetAmount As Long

Dim CTradeDate As Long

Dim CPaymentDate As Long

Dim CMaturity As Long

Dim CNominal As Long

Dim Label As Variant

Dim ra As Range

Dim T() As Variant

Dim DSum As Double

Dim DSum2 As Double

Dim p2 As Variant

Dim Address As String

l = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

p = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

ps = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Dim CTPY As String

Dim VALUEDATE As Date

Dim Contacts As String


ReDim T(p + 1, 8)


For i = 1 To l

If Cells(1, i).Value = "Value Date" Then VALUEDATE = Cells(2, i).Value

Next i



For i = 1 To l

If Cells(1, i).Value = "Counterparty" Then CTPY = Cells(2, i).Value

Next i



'Primo
Set ra = Cells.Find(What:="Sicovam", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

If ra Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Sicovam not found")



        Else

Dim SI() As Variant

i = 0

ReDim SI(0)

Range(ra, ra.End(xlDown)).Select

 i = 0

For Each cell In Range(ra, ra.End(xlDown))
     SI(i) = cell
    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve SI(i)
Next


End If

'Secondo

Set ra = Cells.Find(What:="Trade ID", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If ra Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Trade ID not found")



        Else

Dim TI() As Variant

 i = 0

ReDim TI(0)

        Range(ra, ra.End(xlDown)).Select

       i = 0
      For Each cell In Range(ra, ra.End(xlDown))
     TI(i) = cell
    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve TI(i)
Next


    End If

'Terzo

Set ra = Cells.Find(What:="Business Event", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If ra Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Business Event not found")



        Else
 Dim BE() As Variant

 i = 0

 ReDim BE(0)

        Range(ra, ra.End(xlDown)).Select

       i = 0
      For Each cell In Range(ra, ra.End(xlDown))
     BE(i) = cell
    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve BE(i)
Next


    End If

'Quarto

Set ra = Cells.Find(What:="Net Amount", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If ra Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Net Amount not found")



        Else

 Dim NA() As Variant

 i = 0

 ReDim NA(0)

        Range(ra, ra.End(xlDown)).Select

       i = 0
      For Each cell In Range(ra, ra.End(xlDown))
     NA(i) = cell
    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve NA(i)
Next


    End If

'Quinto

Set ra = Cells.Find(What:="Trade Date", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If ra Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Trade Date not found")


        Else

 Dim TD() As Variant

 i = 0

 ReDim TD(0)

        Range(ra, ra.End(xlDown)).Select

       i = 0
      For Each cell In Range(ra, ra.End(xlDown))
     TD(i) = cell
    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve TD(i)
Next

 End If

'Sesto

Set ra = Cells.Find(What:="Payment Date", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If ra Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Payment Date not found")


        Else

 Dim PD() As Variant

 i = 0

 ReDim PD(0)

        Range(ra, ra.End(xlDown)).Select

       i = 0
      For Each cell In Range(ra, ra.End(xlDown))
     PD(i) = cell
    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve PD(i)
Next

 End If

'Settimo

Set ra = Cells.Find(What:="Maturity", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If ra Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Maturity not found")


        Else

 Dim MA() As Variant

 i = 0

 ReDim MA(0)

        Range(ra, ra.End(xlDown)).Select

       i = 0
      For Each cell In Range(ra, ra.End(xlDown))
     MA(i) = cell
    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve MA(i)
Next

 End If


'Ottavo

Set ra = Cells.Find(What:="Nominal", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If ra Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Nominal not found")


        Else

 Dim NO() As Variant

 i = 0

 ReDim NO(0)

        Range(ra, ra.End(xlDown)).Select

       i = 0
      For Each cell In Range(ra, ra.End(xlDown))
     NO(i) = cell
    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve NO(i)
Next

 End If

For i = 0 To p

T(i, 1) = SI(i)

Next i



For i = 0 To p

T(i, 2) = TI(i)

Next i


For i = 0 To p

T(i, 3) = BE(i)

Next i


For i = 0 To p

T(i, 4) = NA(i)

Next i


For i = 0 To p

T(i, 5) = TD(i)

Next i


For i = 0 To p

T(i, 6) = PD(i)

Next i


For i = 0 To p

T(i, 7) = MA(i)

Next i


For i = 0 To p

T(i, 8) = NO(i)

Next i



With Application.WorksheetFunction
   DSum = .Sum(.Index(T, 0, 5))
End With


DSum2 = Int(DSum * 100)
DSum = DSum2 / 100

T(p, 4) = DSum
T(p, 0) = "TOTAL"



Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


ActiveSheet.Range("B" & p + 1 & ":I" & 2 * p + 1) = T()

ActiveSheet.Range("B" & p + 1 & ":I" & 2 * p + 1).Copy




'For i = 1 To p2

'If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Value = CTPY Then Address = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 4).Value


'Next i





       Address = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CTPY, _
              Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B:D"), 3, 1)




On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = Address
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Amount to confirm Value Date" & " " & VALUEDATE & " " & CTPY
        .Body = "Hello, " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Could you confirm the net amount below?" & T(p + 1, 8)
        .Attachments.Add ""
        .Display

End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing





End Sub
```