# Hyperlink with file exist

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to view a pdf document with name of file in a textbox and a button to view this file.

When the pdf file is in the path it opens.
When it is not there when I click the button nothing happens.

I need to add a msgbox to pop out if the pdf file is not found.

I added File exist function. I don't know if it is the correct method or if there is an easier way to add a msgbox to hyperlink if file is not there.

The problem with my code is that:
If the file is there, it opens normally but shows the msgbox "No Documents Found."
If the file is not there it shows the msgbox "No Documents Found." as well.

```vb
Sub viewdoc()

On Error Resume Next

Dim mypath As String
Dim filename As String

filename = frmDELEGATION.txtLedger.Value

mypath = "E:\4-2022\" & filename & ".pdf"

ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink mypath

If Not FileExists(mypath, filename) Then
    MsgBox "No Documents Found ."
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub


Function FileExists(ByVal mypath As String, ByVal filename As String) As Boolean

    FileExists = (Dir(mypath & filename & ".pdf") <> "")
    
End Function
```

Comment: Your `mypath` variable has a filename in it, so when you pass it to `FileExists` is concatenating the filename again at the end of the filename that is in the `mypath` variable - and of course, that file does not exist. It would look something like this: `"E:\4-2022\test.pdftest.pdf"`

Comment: So from the file exist funtion should I remove the ".pdf"?

Comment: thank you worked when I removed it, I have 3 macros with the same code but different folders. should the FileExist function filename and path change? like path1 and filename1? forgive my other question but related to same code.

Comment: Intead of `If Not FileExists(mypath, filename) Then` use `If Dir(mypath) = "" Then` - and then you won't need that function at all.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` hides errors so you cannot fix them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31753201/vba-how-long-does-on-error-resume-next-work/31753321#31753321 "you should almost NEVER use it. You should figure out why the error occurs and code to handle it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### View Document

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ViewDoc1() ' improve e.g. 'ViewLedger'!
    ViewDocument "E:\4-2022", frmDELEGATION.txtLedger.Value
End Sub

Sub ViewDocument( _
        ByVal FolderPath As String, _
        ByVal FileBaseName As String, _
        Optional ByVal FileExtension As String = ".pdf")
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "View Document"

    If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then
        FolderPath = FolderPath & Application.PathSeparator
    End If
    
    If Len(Dir(FolderPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The path """ & FolderPath & """ doesn't exist.", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Left(FileExtension, 1) <> "." Then
        FileExtension = "." & FileExtension
    End If
    
    Dim fName As String: fName = FileBaseName & FileExtension
    Dim fPath As String: fPath = FolderPath & fName
 
    If Len(Dir(fPath)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The file """ & fName & """ was not found in the folder """ _
            & FolderPath & """.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    On Error Resume Next
        ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink fPath
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```