# Set email due date using Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to set the due date for all selected emails in Outlook.

The following code change due date for mails with due date.

It does nothing for mails where no due date has been set.

I was hoping for some command like below for reminders, but it does not seem to exist.

```
objMail.DueDateSet = True
```

Full code:

```vb
Sub ChangeDueDate()
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim DueDate As Date

    DueDate = InputBox("Enter new due date (dd.mm.yyyy):")
    
    For Each objItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If TypeOf objItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
            Set objMail = objItem
            On Error Resume Next
            'XXX propable here it should state something that due date is "True"

            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                'objMail.ReminderSet = True  -old trial
                'objMail.ReminderTime = DueDate -old trial
                objMail.TaskDueDate = DueDate
                objMail.TaskDueDate = DueDate
                objMail.TaskStartDate = DueDate
            End If

            objMail.Save

        End If
    Next objItem
End Sub
```

Comment: InputBox returns a string. Convert with `CDate`. Test with a date where both day and month are less than 13 and not the same.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is rarely appropriate and often fatal. You may remove it and the apparently backward test `If Err.Number <> 0 Then`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31753201/vba-how-long-does-on-error-resume-next-work/31753321#31753321

Comment: Inserting `Debug.print objMail.IsMarkedAsTask: Stop` before `objMail.TaskDueDate = DueDate` what does it return (in both cases)?

Comment: Thanks both for your comments.
Indeed I did not think about the inputbox returning a string, I added the Cdate there. Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem either.
Adding your code @FaneDuru returns: 'true' on cases previously marked mails, and 'false' on fresh mails

Comment: And is it a correlation in terms of allowing `TaskDueDate` or not? Theoretically the ones returning `False` should allow setting `TaskDueDate`.  If so, you should preliminary try `objMail.ClearTaskFlag`...

Comment: Assign an appropriate value to [MarkAsTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.markastask) from [OlMarkInterval enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olmarkinterval) so `IsMarkedAsTask` is not false

Answer (score 1):

From [OlMarkInterval enumeration (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olmarkinterval)

```
Name          Value   Description
olMarkComplete  5   Mark the task as complete.  
olMarkNextWeek  3   Mark the task due next week.  
olMarkNoDate    4   Mark the task due with no date.  
olMarkThisWeek  2   Mark the task due this week.  
olMarkToday     0   Mark the task due today.  
olMarkTomorrow  1   Mark the task due tomorrow.
```

```vb
Sub ChangeDueDate()

    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objMail As mailItem
    Dim dueDate As Date
    
    Dim defaultDate As Date
    defaultDate = Date + 7
    
    dueDate = InputBox("Enter new due date (dd.mm.yyyy):", , defaultDate)
    
    For Each objItem In ActiveExplorer.selection
    
        If TypeOf objItem Is mailItem Then
        
            Set objMail = objItem
            
            With objMail
                
                Debug.Print
                Debug.Print ".Subject..........: " & .Subject
                Debug.Print " .IsMarkedAsTask..: " & .IsMarkedAsTask
                
                Debug.Print
                Debug.Print "olMarkTomorrow"
                .MarkAsTask olMarkTomorrow
                
                Debug.Print " .IsMarkedAsTask..: " & .IsMarkedAsTask
                
                Debug.Print " .TaskDueDate..: " & .TaskDueDate
                Debug.Print " .TaskStartDate: " & .TaskStartDate
                
                Debug.Print
                Debug.Print "olMarkNextWeek"
                .MarkAsTask olMarkNextWeek
                Debug.Print " .TaskDueDate..: " & .TaskDueDate
                Debug.Print " .TaskStartDate: " & .TaskStartDate
                
                ' Any OlMarkInterval is sufficient to allow custom dates
                Debug.Print
                Debug.Print "olMarkNoDate"
                .MarkAsTask olMarkNoDate
                
                Debug.Print " dueDate: " & dueDate
                
                .TaskDueDate = dueDate
                .TaskStartDate = dueDate - 4
                Debug.Print " .TaskDueDate..: " & .TaskDueDate
                Debug.Print " .TaskStartDate: " & .TaskStartDate
                
                Debug.Print
                Debug.Print " .ReminderTime.: " & .ReminderTime
                .ReminderSet = True
                .ReminderTime = dueDate - 2
                Debug.Print " .ReminderTime.: " & .ReminderTime
                
            End With

            objMail.Display ' objMail.Save
            
        End If
        
    Next objItem
    
End Sub
```